# Irreducibility of $1+X+\ldots+X^{p-1}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Show that the polynomial:

$$g(X)=1+X+X^2+\ldots+X^{p-1}$$

is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $p$ is prime.

I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: You could substitute $x=y+1$ and apply Eisenstein's criterion... (I wouldn't have come up with this myself neither, so don't worry. There should be a more straightforward way.)

Comment: Barto's suggestion is typical and has been done many, many times on MSE.

Comment: The Eisenstein trick is the simplest and quickest way to prove this (possibly except for the cases $p=2$ or $3$)

Comment: can you show the next step on this trick? im not sure wether i should be expnding out the brackets or not, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $X=u+1$. $g(u)=g(X+1)=\dfrac{(X+1)^p-1}{X}=X^{p-1}+pX^{p-2}+\cdots +p$.
Then use Eisenstein's criterion. The constant term $p$ is not divisible by $p^2$ though the other coefficients are divisible by $p$.

Comment: please could you explain how you get from the fraction to the final line? thanks

Comment: you develop $(X+1)^p$ using binomial formula: the constant term is obviously $1$ and it is a classical result that $C_p^k$ is divisible by $p$ for $0<k<p$.